# Resharper warns that it may be null, but will I run into problems in the future?

Tags: c#, .net, linq, resharper

I recently converted my code to more LINQ based code. But ReSharper warns me that the FindAsync function may return null. I don't want to check for null as I'm a bit obsessed with order. Does not checking for null cause problems in the future?

One of the old methods:

```cs
public async Task<IList<Post>> GetPostsByTagIdAsync(int tagId)
{
    var posts = new List<Post>();
    var postIds = context.PostsTags
        .Where(pt => pt.TagId == tagId)
        .Select(p => p.PostId);

    foreach (var id in postIds)
        posts.Add(await context.Posts.FindAsync(id));

    return posts;
}
```

New version:

```cs
public async Task<IList<Post>> GetPostsByTagIdAsync(int tagId) => 
    await context.PostsTags
        .Where(pt => pt.TagId == tagId)
        .Select(p => context.Posts.FindAsync(p.PostId).Result)
        .ToListAsync();
```

Comment: "FindAsync function may return null. I don't want to check for null" ok, so what's the problem here? What do you want to do when it _does_ return null, or can you take the responsibility in ensuring that it will never return null?

Comment: "will i run into problems" - well, you could try what happens if you have null there. also: calling `.Result` on an async method can lead to deadlocks. that's a bad thing to do. and you should rather populate your objects with `.Include()`. currently you're making one round trip to the database for _every_ post.

Comment: Take a step back and get rid of that `.Result`. That's a huge red flag, especially when you were awaiting it in the original. `FindAsync` is a crutch. You can do a proper query by `p.PostId` that can generate SQL within the outer query. What you need here is a join, or depending on your model, you can use navigation properties from `PostTag` to `Post` with a `Posts` property. It's time to embrace the EF mapping paradigm. The warning is only the beginning, because I suspect it won't be able to convert async code to a query, regardless of whether it has `await` or `.Result`.

Comment: Imagine you are this guy: "_If i don't use the seatbelt and don't buckle up, will i crash with my car?_" Clearly the answer is "No, not necessarily". But if you get in a crash, oh boy, will you wish you had buckled up... ;-)

Comment: The return value can be null, if you don't null check your program can blow up, unless you handle the exception, it's a fact, and ReSharper is informing you about that fact. Do with it what you will, but I suspect that idea *I don't like null check* won't get you very far.

Comment: That desire to convert to "more LINQ code" will not lead to anything good, especially if you are willing to even sacrifice null checks for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both versions are ineffective. Better to ask for Posts in one database roundtrip.

```cs
public Task<IList<Post>> GetPostsByTagIdAsync(int tagId)
{
    var query = 
        from pt in context.PostsTags
        join p in context.Posts on pt.PostId equals p.Id
        where pt.TagId == tagId
        select p;

    return query.ToListAsync();
}
```

Also query can be simplified if you have right navigation properties

```cs
public Task<IList<Post>> GetPostsByTagIdAsync(int tagId) => 
    context.PostsTags
        .Where(pt => pt.TagId == tagId)   
        .Select(pt => pt.Post)
        .ToListAsync();
```

Note that, I have removed `async` - it will also speedup execution, because compiler do not create additional state machine for handling asynchronous operations.